# implementing data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

We have m different products (numbered from 1 to m). the tender is open for m days, during these days n people gives an offer to buy(each offer is for one product),
At the end of each day the product (form all products that not yet been sold) with the highest offer will be sold .

we should implement a data structure which provides the following operations:

1. Init (m)-> initializes the DS with m elements without offers
2. Bid(j,p)-> adds an offer with price p to the product j in complexity O(1) amortized
3. Sell-> sells the product with the highest offer. return j (the product which was sold) and p (the price in which the product was sold) in complexity O(log m) amortized .

I tried to solve the question by using fibonacce heaps:

- we create a new fib heap and insert m times (the products with key j and info null)
- I use the idea of decrease key in fib heaps and switch the info with the new p in
- I use the idea of delete min to delete the max

So in order to solve the problem I think that I should use max heaps and not min heaps, this makes me think that I'm in the wrong way.

Someone can help me to get the true solution ?! **

Comment: Yes, you need a max heap. Other than that, the solution you outline is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can get O(log M) for Bid(), and O(1) for Sell() by keeping a hash table of products to maximum bid, and a list of product sorted by maximum bid.

For Bid() you update the table if needed, and updated the list with a binary search if needed; For Sell() you simply pop the top item from the list and get the price from the map.

Comment: Don't see how you can do Bid in O(log n) with a list. If the list is a doubly-linked list, then moving the item when a new bid is placed requires an O(n) search. If the list is maintained in an array, then finding the new spot is O(log n), but actually inserting it will be O(n) because you have to move everything down to make a space.

Comment: we got this problem after learning about binary heaps, binomial heaps, lazy binomial heaps and fib heaps, so I think that the answer should be using the idea of those data structures.
According to the complexity required above this question makes me think of using fib heaps, but selling the max (instead of min in fib )and increasing the info(instead of decreasing the key in fib) makes it hard to me to complete the solution.